# ejabberd registration_timeout infinity doesn't work

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd

I've installed ejabberd 2.1.11 and I've found that I have to put `registration timeout` in the server configuration file.

```
{registration_timeout, infinity}
```

to disable this feature. But I've tried

```
{registration_timeout, infinity}

{registration_timeout, 0}

{registration_timeout, disabled}
```

but i did not get any progress. Please help me with Your advices.
After changing the `congfig file`, i reload the server.
I'm putting this line in global config and in local module. Absolutely nothing.

Comment: Of the ones you've tried, infinity is definitely the one you want (infinity is a special atom in Erlang). Perhaps it's not using the configuration file you're editing?

Not sure if ejabberd lets you connect to the erlang shell, but if it does, check the output of application:get_env(ejabberd, registration_timeout)

Answer (score 1):

Answer where to put `{registration_timeout, infinity}`

Can be found in [here](http://siddharth-ravichandran.com/2010/07/16/ejabberd-resource-constraint-users-are-not-allowed-to-register-accounts-so-fast/)

I was able to apply this setting on ejabberd 2.1.11, by setting this option right next to the ACL options section for instance, like the following:

`%% In-band registration
{access, register, [{allow, all}]}.
{registration_timeout, infinity}.`

You do not have to put it within the Module section (i.e. mod_register), where it seemed the most obvious section at first.

Comment: Please try to explain your answer from the link you provide.

Answer (score 0):

although it's too late but to be submitted for others
I'm using Ejabbred version 20.04 and after a while searching and try and error used

```
registration_timeout: infinity
```

above the "acl" section and it's worked fine for me.